# High Eigen values always for Edge detection

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, edge-detection, eigenvalue, corner-detection

I am trying to understand Harris detector, using the explanation [here](https://matlabcorner.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/does-harris-corner-detector-finds-corners-intuitive-explanation-to-harris-corner-detector/). As per explanation, I understand, if we calculate the eigen values, then,

[image]

However, when I try to calculate the eigen values are always high. Below is my main image from which I extract parts to calculate eigen values.

[image]

For a flat area with no visible features, I get this distribution (on right most) which is good, but eigen values are large 
260935.70201362,434796.29798638

[image]

For a linear edge, also I get high eigen values: 16290305.45393251   567780.54606749

[image]

For corner, it is expected to get high values, but now I am doubtful if these high values are correct due to above cases.

8958127.80563239 10986758.19436761

[image]

Here is my method, translated from matlab code [here](https://matlabcorner.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/does-harris-corner-detector-finds-corners-intuitive-explanation-to-harris-corner-detector/). Its the vals value I directly get from numpy's linear algebra library.

```
def plot_derivatives_1(img_rgb, mode=1):
    '''
    img_rgb = image in rgb color space (3 channeled)
    '''
    img_1c = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if mode == 1:  # method 1 derivative
        Ix = cv2.Sobel(img_1c, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
        Iy = cv2.Sobel(img_1c, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
    else:
        # another method of derivatives
        dx = np.array([
            [-1, 0, 1],
            [-1, 0, 1],
            [-1, 0, 1]
            ]);

        dy = np.transpose(dx)
        Ix = signal.convolve2d(img_1c, dx, mode='valid')
        Iy = signal.convolve2d(img_1c, dy, mode='valid')    
        Ix, Iy = Ix.astype(np.float64), Iy.astype(np.float64) # else gaussian blur later is failing

    # yet to solve why we need A and eigen outputs
    A = np.array([
        [ np.sum(Ix*Ix), np.sum(Ix*Iy) ],
        [ np.sum(Ix*Iy), np.sum(Iy*Iy) ]
    ])
    vals, V = linalg.eig(A)
    lamb = vals/np.max(vals)
    print('lambda values:{}'.format(vals))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(20,5))
    ax[0].imshow(img_rgb);ax[0].set_title('Input Image')
    ax[1].imshow(Ix, cmap='gray');ax[1].set_title('$I_x = \dfrac{\partial I}{\partial x}$')
    ax[2].imshow(Iy, cmap='gray');ax[2].set_title('$I_y = \dfrac{\partial I}{\partial y}$')    
    ax[3].scatter(Ix, Iy);ax[3].set_xlim([-200,200]);ax[3].set_ylim([-200,200]);
    ax[3].set_aspect('equal');ax[3].set_title('Derivatives Distribution');
    ax[3].set_xlabel('Ix');ax[3].set_ylabel('Iy')
    ax[3].axvline(x=0, color = 'r');ax[3].axhline(y=0, color ='r')
    plt.tight_layout();plt.show()    

    return Ix, Iy
```

A sample call for a case (here shown for corner).

```
img = cv2.imread(SRC_FOLDER + 'checkersandbooksmall_sample_6.jpg')
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

Ix, Iy = plot_derivatives_1(img_rgb, mode=1)
```

I use jupyter notebook and the code is just built as I try to understand the concept.

What am I doing wrong to get high eigen values always for all cases?

The sample images used for above cases could be found [here](https://postimg.cc/gallery/2l7q475hs/)

Comment: Your gradient seems to be rescaled. They should be signed values, centered on the origin.